# How do I call a method from a UIbutton selector?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, methods

How do I call this method from the button selector code I have below:

```
- (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *)imageToEdit

{

    AFPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];

    [editorController setDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

here's the UIButton I'm trying to call the method with:

```
//edit button
UIButton *editButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[editButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(editBtnTouch)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[editButton setTitle:@"Effects" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


**// the following line shows the selector where I'm unsure how to call the method from the code above**
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayEditorForImage:)] &&
        ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
        // Retina display
        editButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 320.0, 60.0, 40.0);


} else {
    editButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 315.0, 60.0, 40.0);
}

[self.view addSubview:editButton];
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the selector you add to the button is called, the button itself will be passed as the first argument if the selector allows for one. In order to get a reference to your image, you would either need to do this (assuming the image you want is the background image for the button):

```
- (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIImage* imageToEdit = [sender backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    AFPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];

    [editorController setDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Or you would need to make a custom UIButton that has an extra property for the associated image, and then just access the image through the button in the selector:

```
- (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIButton*)sender {
    if([sender isKindOfClass:[YourCustomButtonClass class]]) {
        UIImage* imageToEdit = ((YourCustomButtonClass*)sender).customImageProperty;

        AFPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];

        [editorController setDelegate:self];

        [self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Edit:

You seem to be confused as to how to make a `UIButton` call a method on when it is tapped. You need to add the object which defines the method as the button's target (in this case `self`), add the method as the selector, and to called the method when the button is tapped use the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. So your code would be:

```
[editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayEditorForImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: thanks for the post. the image I want to be past isn't the button background image. It's an image that's on the view instead.

Comment: Okay. As long as you have a reference to the image when the selector is called, you're good to go.

Comment: what do I put in here: respondsToSelector:@selector(displayEditorForImage:) at the moment I get an unrecognized selector sent to instance error message...

Comment: So you want the `displayEditorForImage:` selector to be called when the button is pressed?

Comment: I just want to call this method from a button - (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIButton*)sender { }; my method call syntax is wrong I think. thanks again :)